# Save/Copy a file from Bundle to Desktop using NSSavePanel

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsbundle, nssavepanel

I’m creating a macOS app which ships with some .zip files within its Bundle directory.

Users should be able to save these files from my app to a custom directory.

I found `NSSavePanel` and thought it is the right approach — that’s what I have so far:

```
@IBAction func buttonSaveFiles(_ sender: Any) {

    let savePanel = NSSavePanel()

    let bundleFile = Bundle.main.resourcePath!.appending("/MyCustom.zip")

    let targetPath = NSHomeDirectory()
    savePanel.directoryURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: targetPath.appending("/Desktop")) 
    // Is appeding 'Desktop' a good solution in terms of localisation?

    savePanel.message = "My custom message."
    savePanel.nameFieldStringValue = "MyFile"
    savePanel.showsHiddenFiles = false
    savePanel.showsTagField = false
    savePanel.canCreateDirectories = true
    savePanel.allowsOtherFileTypes = false
    savePanel.isExtensionHidden = true

    savePanel.beginSheetModal(for: self.view.window!, completionHandler: {_ in })

}
```

I couldn’t find out how to 'hand over' the `bundleFile` to the `savePanel`.

**So my main question is:** How can I save/copy a file from the app bundle to a custom directory?

Additional questions depending `NSSavePanel`: 1) It seems that it’s not localized by default (my Xcode scheme is set to German, but the panel appears in English), do I have to customize that by myself? 2) Is there a way to present the panel expanded by default?

Comment: Running a search for bundle or NSBundle would help.

Comment: @ElTomato I already used `Bundle` for finding the path to the bundleFile (see my code above). It does not help me with my described issues.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that...  Let me think, and I'll get back with you.

Comment: I would use runModal as Eric says.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `Bundle.main.url` to get your existing file URL, then get the destination URL with the panel, then copy the file. The panel doesn't do anything to files, it just gets their URL.

Example:

```
// the panel is automatically displayed in the user's language if your project is localized
let savePanel = NSSavePanel()

let bundleFile = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "MyCustom", withExtension: "zip")!

// this is a preferred method to get the desktop URL
savePanel.directoryURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .desktopDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

savePanel.message = "My custom message."
savePanel.nameFieldStringValue = "MyFile"
savePanel.showsHiddenFiles = false
savePanel.showsTagField = false
savePanel.canCreateDirectories = true
savePanel.allowsOtherFileTypes = false
savePanel.isExtensionHidden = true

if let url = savePanel.url, savePanel.runModal() == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton {
    print("Now copying", bundleFile.path, "to", url.path)
    // Do the actual copy:
    do {
        try FileManager().copyItem(at: bundleFile, to: url)
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
} else {
    print("canceled")
}
```

Also, note that the panel being expanded or not is a user selection, you can't force it from your app.

Comment: Thank you so much! Great solution, works fine. Do you also have any idea why the `NSSavePanel` is not translated/localized? I thought all system-provided UI elements should display in the relevant language automatically.

Comment: You're welcome. The panel will automatically be in the user's language *if* [your project is localized](http://take.ms/x5P8a). Adding a new language from the list will be sufficient, no need to actually implement localization if you don't want to - but you have to at least add the languages in this list, because the panel will need them.

Comment: [Proper link for the Xcode screenshot](https://monosnap.com/file/P6rGrVhQsGaquhVdlzMNDK0FUVXFq6.png) for adding localization.