# NSSavePanel does nothing

Tags: swift, cocoa, nssavepanel

The following code does nothing. No error messages, no save dialog. Why?

```
let FS = NSSavePanel()
FS.canCreateDirectories = true
FS.allowedFileTypes = ["text", "txt"]
FS.begin { (result: Int) -> Void in
    if result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton {
        let exportedFileURL = FS.url
}
}
```

Comment: In which environment / context ?

Comment: Try using the runModal method

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nssavepanel/1525357-runmodal

Comment: runModal does produce a dialog, though I can't see from the docs how to get the results out of it; nor why begin doesn't work in the first place.

Comment: What do you do right after this? Closing any windows?

Comment: "how to get results out of it" See http://stackoverflow.com/a/41198269/2227743

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that provides the final piece of the puzzle. So far, I'm just testing these lines in a script: not doing anything else. Would be nice to know why the original code doesn't work, though.

Comment: `I'm just testing these lines in a script` This might be the cause of your issue. Because `runModal` is synchronous, but `begin` is asynchronous. If your script does not maintain the run loop, it will exit before `begin` has been executed.